# Moving text associated with \underbrace downward

Tags: underbrace

Is there a way to move the text associated with an `\underbrace{}` downward?  I've attempted to depict what I mean in the marked-up image below.  The text "Thermal Conduction" does not need to be contained with in the left and right parentheses, nor the square braces.  The goal is to reduce the overall height of the actual equation by moving the text outside the parentheses.

In case it is helpful, here is the raw latex used to generate the heat transport equation in porous media (shown below):

```
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{\left( 1+ \frac{1- \phi}{\theta} \frac{C_{P_{s}}}{C_{P_{w}}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w} \right) \frac{\partial \left( \theta T \right) }{\partial t}}_\text{change in stored energy}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \left[ \theta \left( \underbrace{\frac {k_{T_{bulk}}}{\theta C_{P_{w}} \rho_w}}_{\text{Thermal} \atop \text{Conduction}} + \alpha \frac{\mathrm{q}}{\theta} \right) \cdot \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j} \right] - \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \left( \theta v_i T \right) + q'_s T_s + \frac{\theta \gamma_w }{C_{p_{w}}} + \frac{ \left( 1 - \phi \right) \gamma_s }{C_{p_{w}}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this question off topic because it  is about Word not LaTeX.  Even though the Word equation editor supports a LaTeX like syntax it is not actually LaTeX.

Comment: What about replacing `\left( \right)` by `\Bigl( \Bigr)`?

Comment: @AlanMunn But doesn't the question extend to pure latex, how would one move the underbrace and the text downward and outside of the parentheses?

Comment: @user2256085 No, because the underlying mechanism is completely different, even if some subset of the syntax is superficially in common.  And since almost nobody here actually uses Word (or if they do, not for math) any answer you get will only work by accident.

Comment: @user2256085: So can you supply your own LaTeX and it will render accordingly? For example, if you can edit the raw LaTeX, what happens when you add (say) `\relax` before the `\underbrace`?

Comment: @Werner I've edited the question by dropping mention of the use MS Word and tested the raw latex in a non-Word interpreter.   Because the equation still renders as desired, but with the `\underbrace` text still inside the parentheses, I standby the original solicitation for help, how would I move the `\underbrace` and associated text downward using the updated latex provided in the original post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're able to update the raw LaTeX code provided, you can manually choose the appropriate delimiter height with `\biggl`...`\biggr` pairs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Original equation:
\begin{equation*}
  \underbrace{
    \left(
      1 + \frac{1 - \phi}{\theta} \frac{C_{P_s}}{C_{P_w}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w}
    \right)
    \frac{\partial \left( \theta T \right)}{\partial t}}_\text{change in stored energy}
    =
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
    \left[
      \theta
      \left(
        \underbrace{
          \frac{k_{T_{bulk}}}{\theta C_{P_w} \rho_w}
        }_{\text{Thermal} \atop \text{Conduction}}
        +
        \alpha \frac{\mathrm{q}}{\theta}
      \right) \cdot \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}
    \right]
    -
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
    \left(
      \theta v_i T
    \right)
    + q'_s T_s + \frac{\theta \gamma_w}{C_{P_w}} + \frac{\left( 1 - \phi \right) \gamma_s}{C_{P_w}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w}
\end{equation*}

\noindent Modified equation:
\begin{equation*}
  \underbrace{
    \biggl(
      1 + \frac{1 - \phi}{\theta} \frac{C_{P_s}}{C_{P_w}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w}
    \biggr)
    \frac{\partial ( \theta T )}{\partial t}}_\text{change in stored energy}
    =
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
    \biggl[
      \theta
      \biggl(
        \underbrace{
          \frac{k_{T_\text{bulk}}}{\theta C_{P_w} \rho_w}
        }_{\substack{\text{thermal} \\ \text{conduction}}}
        +
        \alpha \frac{\mathrm{q}}{\theta}
      \biggr) \cdot \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}
    \biggr]
    -
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\theta v_i T)
    + q'_s T_s + \frac{\theta \gamma_w}{C_{P_w}} + \frac{(1 - \phi) \gamma_s}{C_{P_w}} \frac{\rho_s}{\rho_w}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Other minor changes include:

- Removal of unnecessary `\left`...`\right` combinations
- `\text{bulk}`
- `\substack{\text{thermal} \\ \text{conduction}}`
- Consistent use of `P_w`

Comment: +1 surely. :-) I think that the image of the user is done (or is taken somewhere) with Cambria Math (peraphs) using Word-Office.